# facebook api - get photo not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've developed a script for grabbing the a "photo" (not "picture") from facebook graph.
and it works perfect in CHROME and FF but on IE it's not working,
I've tried setting the photo id manually but it still didn't help, here is the code:

```
<?php

require_once("php-sdk/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'xxx';
$config['secret'] = 'xxx';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$uid = $facebook->getUser(); 
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$photo_id = '141713229354263';
$photo = $facebook->api('/'.$photo_id, 'get' ,  array('access_token' => $access_token ));
?>
```

the error I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request. thrown in /home/insiteme/public_html/test/php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line 1271

but I know the photo_id is good, so I'm lost. I've also tried using: 
$photo = $facebook->api('/'.$photo_id);
and exactly the same error comes up.
also I have user_photos permission to this app.

Comment: dude - don't show you app id and app secret! after you remove them - change them in FB !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do with picture?

This seems like a server code - I would suggest inspecting what IE is sending to the server - cookies, POST & GET parameters, etc.